# What is the shortcut key to toggle the Styles sidebar in Word 2007?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word-2007, styles

What is the shortcut key to toggle the Styles sidebar in Word 2007?
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> brings up "Apply Styles", but I want the sidebar that lists my document styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two options for bringing up the Styles window are:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd>
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

[image: Styles window]